# lucene.net IndexWriter and Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, lucene, lucene.net, azure-webjobs

Ive got an Azure webjob running continuously that triggers based of a queue trigger. The queue contains a list of items that need to be written to my lucene Index. I currently have a lot of items on the queue (over 500k line items) and Im looking for the most effecient way to process it. I keep getting IndexWriter Lock exception when I attempt to 'scale' out the webjob.

Current Setup:

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;

            var host = new JobHost(config);                        
            host.RunAndBlock();
```

Web job function

```
     public static void AddToSearchIndex([QueueTrigger("indexsearchadd")] List<ListingItem> items, TextWriter log)
                {
                    var azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString), "megadata");
                    var findexExists = IndexReader.IndexExists(azureDirectory);
                    var count = items.Count;
                    IndexWriter indexWriter = null;
                    int errors = 0;
                    while (indexWriter == null && errors < 10)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), !IndexReader.IndexExists(azureDirectory), new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_FIELD_LENGTH));
                        }
                        catch (LockObtainFailedException)
                        {
                            log.WriteLine("Lock is taken, Hit 'Y' to clear the lock, or anything else to try again");
                            errors++;
                        }
                    };
                    if (errors >= 10)
                    {
                        azureDirectory.ClearLock("write.lock");
                        indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30), !IndexReader.IndexExists(azureDirectory), new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_FIELD_LENGTH));
 log.WriteLine("IndexWriter lock obtained, this process has exclusive write access to index");
            indexWriter.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(10.0);
            // Parallel.ForEach(items, (itm) =>
            //{
            foreach (var itm in items)
            {
                AddtoIndex(itm, indexWriter);
            }
            //});
    }
```

The method that updates the index items basically looks like this:

```
private static void AddtoIndex(ListingItem item, IndexWriter indexWriter)
        {            
            var doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("id", item.URL, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));
            var title = new Field("Title", item.Title, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES);
 indexWriter.UpdateDocument(new Term("id", item.URL), doc);
}
```

Things I have tried:

1. Set the azure config batch size to the maximum 32
2. Make the method async and use  Task.WhenAll
3. Use parallel for loop

When I try the above, it usually fails with:

```
Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException: Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: AzureLock@write.lock.
 at Lucene.Net.Store.Lock.Obtain(Int64 lockWaitTimeout) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Store\Lock.cs:line 97
 at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Init(Directory d, Analyzer
```

Any suggestions on how I can architecturally set up this web job such that it can process more items in the queue instead of doing it one by one? They need to write to the same index?
Thanks

Comment: I think you should first simplify your problem by just focusing on Lucene. I don't know Lucene, but you're basically looking for the correct **multiple concurrent writer** pattern to use with these Lucene SDK components. I.e., your problem could be simplified as a single exe with mutliple threads all trying to update the index. Once you have that working efficiently, it will translate directly to WebJobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a Lucene sematic problem when multiple processes are trying to write to the Lucene index at the same time. Scaling azure app, using Tasks or parallel for loops will only cause problems, as only one process should write to the Lucene index at the time.

Architectural this is what you should do.

- Ensure only one instance of the webjobs is running at any time – even
  if the Web App scales (e.g. via auto scaling)
- Use maximum webjob batch size (32)
- Commit the Lucene index after each batch to minimize I/O

Ensuring only one instance of the webjob can be done by adding a settings.job file to webjob project. Set the build action to content and copy to output directory. Add the following JSON to the file

```
{ "is_singleton": true }
```

Configure the webjob batch site to maximum

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
config.Queues.BatchSize = 1;
var host = new JobHost(config);                        
host.RunAndBlock();
```

Commit the Lucene index after each batch

```
public static void AddToSearchIndex([QueueTrigger("indexsearchadd")] List<ListingItem> items, TextWriter log)
{
    ...
    indexWriter = new IndexWriter(azureDirectory, …);

    foreach (var itm in items)
    {
        AddtoIndex(itm, indexWriter);
    }
    indexWriter.Commit();
}
```

This will only write to the storage account when the Lucene index is committed, speeding up indexing process. Furthermore, the webjob batching will also speed up message processing (number of messages processed over time and not the individual message process time).

You could add check to see if the Lucene index is locked (write.lock file exists) and unlock the index at the start of the batch process. This should never occur, but everything can happen, so I would add it to be sure.

You could further speed up the indexing process by using a larger Web App instance (mileage may vary) and use faster storage like Azure Premium Storage.

You can read more about the [internals of Lucene indexes on Azure on my blog](http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2011/01/16/using-lucene-net-with-microsoft-azure/).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response :) Changed my approach slightly and got a more efficient process but certainly this would help with my original question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity – how did your solution end up?

Comment: I had a separate job which was doing some pre-processing before adding a list of items to the queue which triggered this webjob. I instead used that same job to write to the index instead of placing the items onto the queue and I found it worked really fast and efficiently with no locks and ofcourse saves some transaction costs. I appreciate the insights though you gave on webjobs esp on the single instance config :)